# get the "display" attribute of the last element

Tags: jquery

Hy guys, How can I get the "display" of the last element?

I'm doing this: `$('.slide').filter(':last').attr("display");` but didn't work.

I tried  `$('.slide:last').attr("display");` and didn't work too.

What am I doing wrong? Tks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the CSS display property?

```
$('.slide:last').css('display')
```

Note that, if you're looking to check whether something is visible, it would be better to ask that question directly, rather than comparing the display property to "block" or "none".

```
$('.slide:last').is(':visible')
```

Answer (score 3):

`display` is a CSS property. Try:

```
$('.slide:last').css("display");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling you're talking about the css `display` property:

```
$('.slide:last').css("display");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.slide:last').css("display");
```